# What type to use for the OmniAuth AuthHash column in postgres?

Tags: omniauth

JSON leads to this error:

```
can't cast OmniAuth::AuthHash
```

String leads to this error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: json = unknown LINE 1: ... "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."omniauth" = $1 LIMIT... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."omniauth" = $1 LIMIT $2
```